# How to remove Git branches that give an error "does not point to a valid object"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-update-ref

I have a Git repository which contains a bunch of remote branches which no longer exist, but when I try to run `git fetch -p` I get an error:

```
error: refs/remotes/origin/bad/branch does not point to a valid object!
```

I can't find any way to fix this.  This branch doesn't exist as a separate file in `.git/refs/remotes` (or anywhere else; I've searched with `find`).  Trying to delete it with `git branch -D` doesn't work:

```
$ git branch -D origin/bad/branch
error: branch 'origin/bad/branch' not found.
$ git branch -D bad/branch
error: branch 'bad/branch' not found.
```

After comments below I tried adding the `-r` option to the `git branch -D` and got this error:

```
$ git branch -D -r origin/bad/branch
error: Couldn't look up commit object for 'refs/remotes/origin/bad/branch'
```

Is there some magic plumbing command I can use to get rid of this ref, short of just deleting the entire workspace which I would really prefer not to do?

Comment: are they upstream to local branches?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "upstream to local branches".  The branches here are the remote branches, yes.

Comment: What is the value of `remote.name.fetch` ? ie, what is the output of `git config remote.${remote_name-origin}.fetch`?

Comment: I get: `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: `git fetch --prune origin` to remove all branches that are no longer in the remote repo and update those that are. `git branch -D -r origin/bad/branch` to remove specific remote branch. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+remote+branch

Comment: As per the question, when I try to run `git fetch --prune` I get the error above.  The goal is to get rid of these branches so that `git fetch --prune` will succeed.  I tried using `git branch -D` as above; when I add the `-r` option I get this error: `error: Couldn't look up commit object for 'refs/remotes/origin/bad/branch'`

Comment: `git update-ref -d <ref>`?

Comment: Aha!!  `git update-ref -d` did it for one of my branches!  I knew there had to be some plumbing command that would just "get rid of it".  Thanks that's very useful, I will try adding it to my script to see what goes wrong next (I have a CI/CD system with hundreds of these workspaces across 60+ servers and probably 80% of them need to be fixed).

Comment: It seems that `git update-ref -d` solved the issue.  If you make an answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will force-delete a remote-tracking branch:

```
git branch -D -r origin/bad/branch
```

But that didn’t work.

When the higher-level commands are too stubborn to do what you want, you
might want to try a lower-level command:

```
git update-ref -d origin/bad/branch
```

#### Manually deleting

Note that manually editing things is generally not recommended. But it
might be necessary. No warranties.

Refs are to my knowledge currently stored[1] in two possible places:

- As files under `.git/refs`
- As a *packed ref* in `.git/packed-refs` (file)

If it’s a file then `origin/bad/branch` is stored at
`.git/refs/origin/bad/branch`. Just deleting that file should be safe.

If it’s a packed ref: open `.git/packes-refs`. I have not read any
technical documentation for this file format but it just looks like a
file on the form:

```
hash<space>full ref path<newline>
```

In which case you might find the ref on a line like:

```
[hash or some nonsense value?]<space>refs/origin/bad/branch<newline>
```

I guess you could just delete that line. But first do it in a backup of
the whole repository (and working tree) just to be safe.

#### Notes

1. There is currently (2024-03-01) ongoing work on a “reftable
   backend”. I don’t know what that concretely is but you should expect
   a binary format which is not as easy to manually muck with.

Comment: Good info here.  indeed the `update-ref` worked and I much prefer that to breaking open a packed-refs file and mucking about in it.  I knew there had to be a plumbing command but I couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

git is not magic. It needs to store its information somewhere and that somewhere is the .git directory. it stores all the configuration, objects and references pertaining to your current project/repository.

`.git/refs` contains all the references you have in your repository.

The `.git/refs/HEADS` list all the references that you're managing locally. If you open any of those files you'll see there is a hash there, this references to the commit that that branch references.  You likely look in there and simply delete the reference to the branch that you're referring too. (keep in mind if that branch doesn't exist in the origin, i.e., your server, you've effectively lost your work unless you can remember your branch name and GC hasnt cleaned up the dangling references.)

its also not hard to figure out that `.git/refs/remotes/` refers to all servers that you've connected your git repo to and there references stored there. In most cases you'll just have an `origin` directory.

If you want to see it in action, rename the `.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory and run `git pull` you'll see the logs show that there are new branches to refer to.

Basically delete the offending branch that's in your local `.git/refs/HEADS` folder that corresponds to the branch giving you a hard time and try again.

Comment: Deleting refs by deleting the backing files (if they are stored as files) is fine if the commands refuse to do so. But you should use a command if you happen to find one that isn’t too stubborn to do it. ;)

Comment: I'm with you, but it seems like OP's problem is with there being a bad ref somewhere, its easier/faster to just delete it.

Comment: I'm well aware that git is not magic, and I'm aware that _usually_ branches are simply files in directories under `.git`.  But as I explained in my question, **that is not the case for these broken branches**.  I don't know where they're being stored, but I did a `find` operation looking for them and they **do not exist**.  `git branch -a | grep badbranch` shows that branch.  `git fetch` gives an error `fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/badbranch`.  But `find .git -name badbranch` returns NO RESULTS.  If it were as simple as deleting a file I would have done it and not asked the question.

Comment: Have you tried running garbage collection? That might get rid of some dangling references.

Comment: Tried `git gc` but no change; still same fatal error.

Comment: Do you have any other remotes configured? (try the suggestion i gave about renaming your origin directory and fetching again, or delete it. )

Comment: I renamed the `refs/origin` directory and now I get `bad object` errors for branches that used to exist when I run `git fetch` or `git pull`.  These repos were created by the CI/CD systems, not me, and their upstream is a `file:///....` repo on the local disk which is a cache of the "real" repo: in the real repo the branches do exist, and in the workspace repo the branches do exist, but in the cached repo they're gone (due to CI/CD machinations, nothing I can do anything about).  I don't care about source in these workspaces but deleting them will lose cores etc. I prefer not to  lose.